Recommendations on the below traffic flows
I plan to block suspicious traffic flows on my network. Do you think any of the following could be a valid flow?

deny tcp any eq 443 any eq 80
deny tcp any eq 80 any eq 80
deny tcp any eq 443 any eq 443
deny tcp any eq 80 any eq 443


It is pretty rare that both the source and destination ports are the same. That is not how the real world works, except in specific circumstances.

I don't know your network, so I can't say for sure. But, it would be rare for a web server to use its listening socket for outbound connections. And then there's the question of why it would be making outbound requests.

Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Those are valid patterns, but unlikely ones.
Very few attackers use http/s ports 80 and 443 as source. More likely is an ephemeral port like with a normal client - which you can‘t block, obviously.

Thank you for the response. Agreed that flows are not valid but I have hardly seen these flows, saw them during an attack. I am planning to block on the Akamai Prolexic DDoS Cloud.
